# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-arrayadapter

I have created a custom Array adapter and i have image view and onclick of that image view i have am opening a Dialogue but it is showing me the  **android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application** 
hers is my code

the below line gives me error

```
if (context != null) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.spread_dialogue);
    dialog.setTitle("New Post");
    dialog.show();
}


public class Customfeedadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Rowfeeds> {

    Context context;
    Rowfeeds feeds;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    ImageView imgview, likeimgview;
    Vector<String> mfeedid = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<String> muserid = new Vector<String>();
    public String guestlist;
    private ProgressDialog simpleWaitDialog;
    public String mssg;
    public String likemssg;

    Vector<String> mfeedlike = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<String> mfeedspread = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<String> mfeeddate = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<String> mfeedtime = new Vector<String>();
    private String likestrng, spreadstng, datestrng, timestrng;

public Customfeedadapter(Context context, int resource, List<Rowfeeds> objects, Vector<String> feedIdvector, Vector<String> userIdvector, Vector<String> feedlikevector, Vector<String> feedspreadvector, Vector<String> feeddatevector, Vector<String> feedtimevector) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.mfeedid = feedIdvector;
    this.muserid = userIdvector;

    this.mfeedlike = feedlikevector;
    this.mfeedspread = feedspreadvector;
    this.mfeeddate = feeddatevector;
    this.mfeedtime = feedtimevector;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView feedlike;
    TextView feedspread;
    TextView feeddate;
    TextView feedtime;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        feeds = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Log.i("imgvectr", ""+mfeedlike.elementAt(position));
            likestrng = "" + mfeedlike.elementAt(position);
            spreadstng = "" + mfeedspread.elementAt(position);
            datestrng = "" + mfeeddate.elementAt(position);
            timestrng = "" + mfeedtime.elementAt(position);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textsimple);
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.showtime);
            holder.feedlike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedlikes);
            holder.feedspread = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.feeddate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feeddatetv);
            holder.feedtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedtime);
        } else //Log.v("else", "else");
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.txtDesc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        //Log.v("getMfeedid", ""+feeds.getMfeedid());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(feeds.getMsg());
        holder.txtDesc.setText("~" + feeds.getUsrname());
        holder.feedlike.setText(likestrng);
        holder.feedspread.setText(spreadstng + " Spreads");
        holder.feeddate.setText(datestrng);
        holder.feedtime.setText(timestrng);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
    }

    // spread icon
    imgview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imgview.setTag(position);
    imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String strng = ""+getItem(position);

            try {
                //Toast.makeText(context,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (context != null) {
                    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.spread_dialogue);
                    dialog.setTitle("New Post");
                    dialog.show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
            }

            /*Log.v("strng", ""+position);
             mfeedid.elementAt(position);
             Log.v("mfeedid.elementAt(position)", ""+mfeedid.elementAt(position));
             String value = ""+mfeedid.elementAt(position);
             new SendApproveValue().execute(value.trim());*/
        }
    });

    likeimgview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    likeimgview.setTag(position);
    likeimgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("strng", "" + position);
            mfeedid.elementAt(position);
            muserid.elementAt(position);
            Log.v("mfeedid.elementAt(position)", "" + mfeedid.elementAt(position));
            Log.v("muserid.elementAt(position)", "" + muserid.elementAt(position));
            String value = "" + mfeedid.elementAt(position);
            String value2 = "" + muserid.elementAt(position);
            new SendlikesValue().execute(value.trim(), value2.trim());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class SendApproveValue extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("param", "= " + param[0]);
        String approvevalue = "" + param[0];
        try {
            Log.i("spreadsInBackground", "spreadsInBackground");
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.21.74/mynetwork/formapi/spreads");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feed_id", approvevalue));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", "5"));
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(postMethod);
            if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String result3 = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                Log.v("spreads_data", "" + result3);
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result3);
                Log.v("msg", "" + jobject.getString("msg"));
                mssg = "" + jobject.getString("msg");
            } else {
                Log.d("spreadsrJSON", "StatusCode " + rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
        //simpleWaitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Wait..", "Sending data");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
        Toast.makeText(context, mssg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context,resultt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //RowItem3 item3 = new RowItem3(/*vector.elementAt(i),*/vector);
        //simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class SendlikesValue extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("param2", "= " + param[0]);
        Log.v("param2", "= " + param[1]);
        String approvevalue = "" + param[0];
        String approvevalue2 = "" + param[1];
        try {
            Log.i("SendlikesValue", "SendlikesValue");
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.21.74/mynetwork/formapi/likes");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feed_id", approvevalue));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", approvevalue2));
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(postMethod);
            if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String result3 = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                Log.v("likes_data", "" + result3);
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result3);
                Log.v("msg", "" + jobject.getString("msg"));
                likemssg = "" + jobject.getString("msg");
            } else {
                Log.d("likesJSON", "StatusCode " + rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("likesException", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
        //simpleWaitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Wait..", "Sending data");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
        Toast.makeText(context, likemssg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //RowItem3 item3 = new RowItem3(/*vector.elementAt(i),*/vector);
        //simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where do you dismiss dialog?

Comment: Try using `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);` instead of `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);`

Comment: you should pass Activity reference to Dialog. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779377/android-custom-dialog-gives-an-error/20779392#20779392

Comment: i am just opening a dilaog on image view click and it is giving me android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application

Comment: @Rehan i am not in Activity , i am in Arrayadapter so i am using the mainActivty's context

Comment: Can you show the declaration code of customfeedadapter

Comment: feedadapter = new Customfeedadapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.feeds,rowfeedlist
     ,feedIdvector,userIdvector,feedlikevector,feedspreadvector,feeddatevector,feedtimevector);

Comment: Use your activity name there i.e. MainActivity.this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose you are passing context from your `Activity ActivityABC` to your `Adapter`. Then create following variable in your adapter

```
Activity mActivity = null;
```

and pass context like this `ActivityABC.this` to variable `mActivity` in our adapter and then display dialog using:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
```

Hope this trick works for you

Comment: actually just specifying getActivity() worked fine